# Can’t find element by Xpath, or the selectors

Tags: python, selenium

I am making an automated JKLM bomb party bot using selenium.py (prank my friends). When it is given a link to a private JKLM, it will go there, confirm the username, but then get stuck on the “join game” button (I get TimeoutException Error).

```
    driver = webdriver.Safari()
    driver.get(link)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[2]/input")))
    element.submit()
    element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='styled joinRound']")))
    element1.click()
```

I have tried Absolute XPath:
`/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button`
Relative XPATH:
`//button[@class='styled joinRound’]`
And Class Name:
`styled joinRound`
Along with Tag Name and CSS selector.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
HTML I am trying to access and click on:

```
<button class="styled joinRound" data-text="joinGame">Join game</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may need to switch to the iframe first in Selenium. I had success with this:

```
import selenium.webdriver

def main():
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://jklm.fun/DKCY')
    driver.switch_to_frame(0)
    xpath = '//div[@class="seating"]/div[@class="join"]/button'
    els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    if els is None or len(els) == 0:
        print('failed to find element')
        return
    els[0].click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

See:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-handle-frames-in-selenium-with-python
- https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames